# Auto-Renewal Subscription - Resubscribe

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, in-app-subscription, auto-renewable

I am finding a strange kind of behaviour with Auto-Renewal Subscription.

Let me explain with an example -

I subscribe for an paid service with 7 days trail period and enjoy the service for 2 or 3 days then cancels the subscription. My Subscription continues for 7 days as they were free trial. Lets says Dates - 20/12/2016 to 26/12/2016. Its fine.

After my free trial subscription expire and i again resubscribe - I have 2 questions here.

If i do the same from my app and apple generated alerts pops up with dates Starting from 03/01/2016, but if resubscribe from settings Start date shows 27/12/2016 -  this creates **** lots of confusion.

Going ahead , I Subscribed from my app and subscription was successful , now I am able to use the paid service. But Apple Didn't charged my CC for this transaction and no INVOICE was sent to me, Where as when i was subscribed with trial I was sent and email about the same.

Keeping these - I went on to check my Purchase History from iTunes and saw that there is transaction of "Type - Subscription Renewal , Unit - 1 @ Rs 400"

Comment: Sometimes Apple manages to provide invoices not in realtime, but a little delayed including more purchases.

Comment: @MatteoCrippa I do understand that but I find that it was not reflected for quite some time.

Comment: the longest time it took a month to receive that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes as stated by Matteo Crippa it took 2 weeks to get updated.